# Programmatically detecting PEAR in PHP

Tags: php, pear

One of my scripts needs PEAR for some additional functionality. I need a way I can detect if PEAR is installed within PHP itself. Since `PEAR.php` would be in the include path if properly installed, I suppose I could check for the existence of `PEAR.php` with `file_exists()` and then check for the PEAR class inside of it to try and determine if it's actually the file I want. Sounds awfully hackish and unreliable though.

Can anybody suggest a better or improved approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if PEAR is installed by requiring the `System.php` file to see if the class exists. This method can be done as instructed here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

System.php is shipped with every PEAR installation, so it would be an easy way to detect it.

```
<?php
require_once 'System.php';
if(class_exists('System')===true) {
   echo 'PEAR is installed!';
} else {
   echo 'PEAR is not installed :(';
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: But if System.php didn't exist wouldn't the script give a fatal error?

Comment: Just wanted to note that the `if(class_exists('System')===true)` can be used shorted as `if(class_exists('System'))` but I set it that way just to give you an example.

Comment: Ah, that is true. You could use `if(file_exists('System.php')) { include('System.php'); }` instead to make sure errors do not pop up in the script.

Comment: Aha. Thanks for confirming my method and helping!

Comment: Turns out you can't use `file_exists()` on `System.php` I ended up having to do something like `if(@include_once("System.php"))` and then check for the class.

Comment: Still confused with this answer. In which path should require_once() be looking?

Answer (score 8):

You could try to use the following setup, rather then using file_exists:

```
$filePath = stream_resolve_include_path('System.php');
if ($filePath !== false)
{
    require_once('System.php'); // you could use $filePath as well
    echo 'PEAR installed';
}
else
{
    echo 'PEAR not installed';
}
```

The tricky part is, PEAR will be most likely added to the current include path. Thats the reason why you can use System.php and not /path/to/pear/System.php. This way you can figure out if PEAR is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
if(@include_once("System.php"))
{
    echo "Pear is installed";
}
else
{
    echo "Nope";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above is not correct. You should use it like so:

```
<?php
include 'System.php';
if(class_exists('System')===true) {
    echo 'PEAR is installed!';
} else {
    echo 'PEAR is not installed :(';
}
?>
```